# create tables country with city

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, relational-database

Which is better--make two tables, one for countries and the other for cities?

```
countries
countery_id pk
country_name

cities
city_id  pk
city_name
country_id   fk
```

or one table for countries and cities

```
id  pk
country_name
city_name
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a separate table for each object approach. (2 tables)

1. It would be easier to maintain and expand (e.g. you'll need to add currency for countries).
2. It promotes data integrity like eliminating the risk of two cities from the same country having its country name spelled differently ("United States", "USA", etc.).
3. It saves disk space (no data duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question.  The "formal" answer is that countries and cities are different entities and you should hence put them in separate tables.

The practical answer is that there may not be much use to having separate tables:

- A city is in exactly one country (although metro areas could span countries).
- Cities never -- or very rarely -- change countries.
- Countries have standardized names and codes.

"Country" could be treated as just an attribute of a "city". But that means repeating a country name through multiple rows.  And such repetition is likely to be problematic, and prone to error.  But this depends on the source of the data.

For me, I think it would come down to three factors.

1. What is the source of data?  If the source is a standardized list of cities and validated country names, I wouldn't have a problem storing them as a single table.  If the source is arbitrary or involves any human input, then I would advise a separate table for `countries`.
2. Is there other information you might want to store about a country, such as language or population?  If so, then you want a separate table for `country`.
3. Do other tables need to reference the countries (for instance a table that listed the official languages)?

In conclusion, I would say there are probably more situations where you want two tables.  But in your very simplistic example, one table might be okay under some circumstances.